# How to show result in particular location in Template in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to show result from **Controller to Template**, it gives me result, but not in proper format. When I'm trying to load **data in template in Container**, the data is loaded but not in container, it **loads in body** part of the page.

> **Note:** I'm fetching data from library class to controller and then it
>   shows in template.

Here is my Controller code:

```
public function index()
   {
        try {             
            $data['run'] = $this->my_fun->run();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->load->view('admin/myfun/view', $data);
   }
```

Here is my template code:

```
<?php init_head(); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php echo $run; ?>
    </div>
<?php init_tail(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my output :

[image]

Comment: Make `var_dump($data['run']); exit;` in controller to check what is format of result.

Comment: It prints NULL at the end of result.

Comment: have you got the output result??

Comment: Yes, I got output, but it comes in Body part, not in template view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to *retain* the output of `$this->my_fun->run()`. This method is probably directly `echo`ing results upon execution. This in turn prints before the template load in CodeIgniter, appearing before the header.

```
public function index()
{
    $data = array();

    try {
        ob_start();
        $this->my_fun->run();
        $run = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $data["run"] = $run;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }

    $this->load->view('admin/myfun/view', $data);
}
```

However it's more preferable to change `$this->my_fun->run()` to return data, not output it.